# Function to create new subsetting dataframes

Tags: r

How do I create many new data frames in R that are subsets of a much larger data frame. The original data frame has 15  columns(ex: a-o)--I want each subset by the value of the third column (ex: one subset is only c=='111_11111', the next subset is only c=='111_10101') (the values of column c are not sequential).

So far I have the following:

```
data <- c([values of column c])
function1.all <- function(x){
  a <- numeric(length(x))
  for(i in seq_along(x)){
    a <- subset(main_data_frame,c==i)
      }
    a
  }
```

Comment: Have a look at `?split` maybe.

Comment: What do you want to do with them? Check out the plyr or dplyr packages to split a data.frame by a variable and then do all sorts of things to each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this, if you're not using factors in the c col, and you get a list as output. I prefer lists for storing relatively large amounts of data frames, since you can always just make the list bigger versus making a new variable.

I'll go over each step of the code in detail:

Find the unique values in your identifier column. In your case with the format (###_#####).

```
un <- unique(main_data_frame[,"c"])
```

Create a list that will store all your data frames inside of it. The list has a length that is equal to the amount of unique ID's, which is also equal to the amount of unique data frames.

```
many.frames <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(un))
```

Lastly, iterate the unique list, pulling the items from the main_data_frame using the subset function. You are basically pulling out all the rows that have your unique ID into this new data frame.

```
for (i in 1:length(un)) {
  many.frames[[i]] <- subset(main_data_frame, c == un[i])
}
```

You can also use:

```
many.frames[[i]] <- main_data_frame[,main_data_frame$c==un[i]]
```

To access any of them, you can use many.frames[[n]], where n is the index of the ID. If you want to pull by id, many.frames[["###_#####"]], just wrap in quotes.

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: The values of the c column are formatted ###_##### for example  111_12123

Comment: Thanks Toby, please let me know if this is all clear. 

Amanda, you should be able to access any data.frame with this subset:

    many.frames[["111_11111"]]

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your data frame is called `df` and the relevant column is named `c`:

```
values <- unique(df$c)

for (i in 1:length(values)) {
    assign(paste0("df", i), df[df$c == values[i],])
}
```

This will create as many data frames as there are unique values in df$c, each numbered df1, df2, etc.

Comment: This only shows the first two columns of the data frame. I need the subsetting data frames to show all  15 columns with the values that correspond to c=="each unique value."

Comment: No, all columns are kept in each df1, df2, etc. Can you check again?